# ImportError: No module named autopy in python

Tags: python

I am working on  a code where I required autopy. I research on autopy after that i install

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

> package but when I again run the program it showing the error

```
ImportError: No module named autopy
```

I am not getting what is the problem how to remove.

Please help me to find out what is the problem and how to fix it. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Did you install a special version of python?  What happens when you type `which python` on the command line?

Comment: @ SethMMorton it's showing /usr/bin/python not showing any special package of python.

Comment: I tried to install with this command----___   pip install autopy
 but its installed but at last stage it's showing     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the package yourself, it's not installed on that computer. You can install it with:

```
pip install autopy
```

[`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) is the most common Python package installer, and is used to download Python packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), the Python Package Index, and you can install it with:

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Autopy isn't in the python stdlib, so it won't be included in the python-dev package. You need to install it separately with [easy_install](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html).